# Quadratic and geometric average

Tags: statistics, average, standard-deviation, quadratics

I'd like to find the find the quadratic average and the geometric average. To do this I have these informations :

The standart deviation, the arithmetic average and the number of values.

I know the formula to get the quadratic and geometric average with values, but in this case I don't have them.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Is that even possible? I think not. Quadratic average yes, but geometric? I doubt it very much.

Comment: Tip: you have the standard deviation, so you have the variance ($s^2$), by squaring. Now, write $s^2 = (1/n) \sum (x-\bar{x})^2 = (\sum x^2)/n - \bar{x}^2$, where $\bar{x}$ is the arithmetic average. (Assuming your variance is the *populational* variance -- if it is not, change the first denominator $n$ to $n-1$ and recalculate).

Comment: Thanks your comment help me a lot ! I got it :). And what's about the geometric average ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the geometric average when $n=3$. Knowing the arithmetic and quadratic average of three numbers $(x,y,z)$ is equivalent to knowing $x+y+z$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2$, while knowing the geometric average means knowing $xyz$. If $xyz$ were a function of the other two, its gradient at any point would be a linear combination of the other two gradients. But
$$
\begin{align*}
  \nabla(x+y+z)&=(1,1,1)\\
  \nabla(x^2+y^2+z^2)&=2(x,y,z)\\
  \nabla(xyz)&=(yz,xz,xy)
\end{align*}
$$
At $(x,y,z)=(1,2,3)$, say, the three gradients are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for the geometric average, there are infinitely many solutions depending on the number of observations.